# Naming enumerated lists referencing the names

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate

Currently I have the following TeX

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item First idea
\item \label{idea:s} Second idea
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Point about \ref{idea:s}
\end{enumerate}
```

I would like to be able to somehow name the lists themselves, and then the reference `idea:s` could be something like `List I.a`, or something like that. How can I name enumerated lists? I was thinking that defining an environment like a `theorem` environment would work, but is there a more preferred way?

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems#Basic_theorems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be what you're after, and uses the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to obtain the appropriate formatting.

A new environment `biglist` is created that has the following default formatting:

- Item labels are given as a Roman numeral indicating the list identifier/name, followed by `.`, followed by the item number (in alphabetic enumeration).
- Item references are given as `List~<label>` where `<label>` is as described above.

This will allow you to use the `enumerate` environment for other lists in your document, while `biglist` is reserved for your "named lists". The formatting, of course (in terms of labelling and referencing) can be modified. Additional options can also be specified via an optional argument to `\begin{biglist}[<other parameters>]`. These include the item separation, indent, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\newcounter{biglist} \renewcommand{\thebiglist}{\Roman{biglist}}%
\newenvironment{biglist}[1][*]
  {\stepcounter{biglist}%
   \begin{enumerate}[label=\thebiglist.\alph*,ref=List~\thebiglist.\alph*,#1]}% \begin{biglist}
  {\end{enumerate}}% \end{biglist}
\begin{document}
\begin{biglist}
\item First idea
\item \label{idea:s} Second idea
\end{biglist}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Point about \ref{idea:s}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}​
```

The above can be made more dynamic by allowing you to specify the name as an optional argument as well, and even choose between something other than (say) `List`, or stick to that as the default.